# How to compare a column in a table from a column in another table in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I am trying to create a calculated column that compares one column to another column in a different table, I want to compare the version of the applications installed in different computers so I can monitor if I am up to date or not. Here are how my tables look like:

Table 1

| App name | Version | ComputerName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adobe Acrobat Reader DC | 19.010.20069 | COMPUTER1 |
| Google Chrome | 87.0.4280.141 | COMPUTER1 |
| Microsoft Edge | 87.0.664.75 | COMPUTER1 |
| SnagIt | 12.4.0 | COMPUTER1 |
| Adobe Acrobat Reader DC | 18.010.20069 | COMPUTER2 |
| Google Chrome | 85.0.4280.141 | COMPUTER2 |
| Microsoft Edge | 84.0.664.75 | COMPUTER2 |
| SnagIt | 11.4.0 | COMPUTER2 |

Table 2

| App name | Required Version |
| --- | --- |
| Adobe Acrobat Reader DC | 19.010.20069 |
| Google Chrome | 87.0.4280.141 |
| Microsoft Edge | 87.0.664.75 |
| SnagIt | 12.4.0 |
| Microsoft Visual Studio | 10.0 |
| Python Launcher | 3.82 |

Expected Outcome

| App name | Version | ComputerName | Compliant Check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adobe Acrobat Reader DC | 19.010.20069 | COMPUTER1 | COMPLIANT |
| Google Chrome | 87.0.4280.141 | COMPUTER1 | COMPLIANT |
| Microsoft Edge | 87.0.664.75 | COMPUTER1 | COMPLIANT |
| SnagIt | 12.4.0 | COMPUTER1 | COMPLIANT |
| Adobe Acrobat Reader DC | 18.010.20069 | COMPUTER2 | NOT COMPLIANT |
| Google Chrome | 85.0.4280.141 | COMPUTER2 | NOT COMPLIANT |
| Microsoft Edge | 84.0.664.75 | COMPUTER2 | NOT COMPLIANT |
| SnagIt | 11.4.0 | COMPUTER2 | NOT COMPLIANT |

I have tried creating the relationship but despite that I can't seem to compare the two tables.

Answer (score 2):

First create an ID column in both tables. I combined the app name and the version to create an unique ID.

```
ID = COMBINEVALUES( "-", Table1[App name], Table1[Version] )
```

Then create a relationship between the tables using the ID columns.

Finally use the following DAX logic to create a calculated column in **Table1**

```
Compliant Check = 
IF( 
    NOT( ISBLANK( RELATED( Table2[ID] ) ) ), 
    "COMPLIANT", 
    "NOT COMPLIANT" 
)
```

This is the expected result:

[image]

Comment: You can even create an ID column using the index column in the query editor which can save some time. :)